# Gatling make a variable or attribute available outside a transformResponse block

Tags: gatling

This is a question about Gatling version 3.3

I would like to save a few keys from a json response and concatenate them, so that I can reuse them in the body of the next request.
What I get from the server from the get request is this:

```
{
    "result": [{
            "label": "Work",
            "addr1": "212 Stephenville St",
            "addr2": "",
            "city": "Massena",
            "zip": "13668",
            "country": "US",
            "region": "US-NY",
            "additionalInfo": "",
            "building": "",
            "floor": "",
            "room": "",
            "phone": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

What I need to have is a variable with addr1 + zip + region + country, meaning:
"212 Stephenville St" + " " + "13668" + " " + "US-NY" + " " + "US"

This is what I was trying to do:

```
  var address0: String = " "
  def getAddresses() = {
    exec(http("GET /addresses")
      .get("/addresses")
      .check(status.is(200))
      .transformResponse {
        (session, response) =>
          if(response.status.code == 200) {
            val jsonResponse: JsValue  = Json.parse(response.body.string)
            address0 = (jsonResponse \ "result" \ 0 \ "addr1").as[String] + (jsonResponse \ "result" \ 0 \ "zip").as[String] + (jsonResponse \ "result" \ 0 \ "region").as[String] + (jsonResponse \ "result" \ 0 \ "country").as[String]
            session.set("address1", address0)
            response
          } else {
            response
          }
      })
      .pause(1)
      .exec {session => println(session); session}
  }
```

I have confirmed that address0 inside the transformResponse block has the value I need, but it is not available outside. I also tried session.set("address1", address0) thinking that it can add a new attribute but it is not present when I do println(session).

**I wonder if someone can provide any help on how to make available the value of address0 outside this block so that I can reuse it in the next request?**

By the way I know I can do the following and it works.

```
  def getAddresses() = {
    exec(http("GET /addresses")
      .get("/addresses")
      .check(status.is(200))
      .check(jsonPath("$.result[0].addr1").saveAs("addr1"))
      .check(jsonPath("$.result[0].zip").saveAs("zip"))
      .check(jsonPath("$.result[0].region").saveAs("region"))
      .check(jsonPath("$.result[0].country").saveAs("country")))
      .pause(1)
      .exec {session => println(session); session}
  }
```

But I would prefer to do it within the transformResponse block if possible

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do this with transformResponse, but I'm not sure it's the best way. What's going wrong in your example is that transformResponse is for modifying the response prior to running checks - it takes the response and the session, and returns a response. Editing the session inside the block doesn't work as sessions are immutable, and you don't get to return the session.

So what you need to do is parse the response as JSON (as you're doing), then add your newly constructed address back into the response and return it before getting the value into the session via check calls.

What would be easier would be to get all the component values via checks, then assemble them into the desired composite and store that into the session - either in a session function or as part of a check transform. This way you wouldn't need to mess around with any custom JSON parsing / construction at all.

```
def getAddresses() = {
exec(http("GET /addresses")
  .get("/addresses")
  .check(status.is(200))
  .check(jsonPath("$.result[0].addr1").saveAs("addr1"))
  .check(jsonPath("$.result[0].zip").saveAs("zip"))
  .check(jsonPath("$.result[0].region").saveAs("region"))
  .check(jsonPath("$.result[0].country").saveAs("country"))
)
.exec(session => session.set("address", session.get("addr1").as[String] + session.get("zip").as[String] + session.get("region").as[String] + session.get("country").as[String]))
```

Comment: Thanks so much James.
For this gatling version (3.3), the "session.get" doesn't work.
So it is like this:

.exec(session => session.set("address", session("addr1").as[String] + session("zip").as[String] + session("region").as[String] + session("country").as[String]))

I now understand the concept of session immutability, thanks for explaining it.
One last question if possible. Do you know why var address0 defined outside the block doesn't get set inside the block? I mean, it is set but its value is not available outside, is it because of the same principle, immutability?

Comment: you've defined it as a var, so you should be able to change it's value. What code are you subsequently using it in? Straight scala code or gatling DSL code?

Comment: I am using it in a subsequent gatling request as a queryParam.

  `def getLocation() = {
    exec(http("GET /v1/location")
      .get("/v1/location")
      .queryParam("address", address0)
      .check(status.is(200))
      .pause(1)
      //.exec {session => println(session); session}
  }`

Basically the value is empty.

Comment: the reason that fails is that the gatling DSL defines immutable builders, so they have the values at the time they are instantiated. So your 'get' that attempts to use address0 gets the value at the time the builder is constructed - " ". To get around this you need to set it as a variable in the session and use it that way